# Oozie Logs Mapreduce JobIds

Tags: java, mapreduce, hive, workflow, oozie

Can we get the all the mapreduce jobid's of an oozie workflow from logs or from anywhere? Also, can we have any information about the mapreduce jobs launched?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wf` command ([Documentaion](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.2.3_Workflow_EL_Functions)). 
It returns the workflow job ID for the current workflow job.
The sintax is:

`${wf:id()}`

Comment: yes but i need individual java mapreduce jobids launched. This is different from the workflow id.